# Graphing a parabola with inputs in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, graphing

so I've created a quadratic equation solver in python, and I want a graph to go along with it. I want this graph to depict the parabola.

a = an input for a in quadratic equation

b = an input for b in quadratic equation

c = an input for c in quadratic equation

y = -b/2*a (vector)

```
import math
a = int(input('Input a: '))
b = int(input('Input b: '))
c = int(input('Input c: '))
discrim = int((b*b) - 4*a*c) 
posi = (-b + (math.sqrt(discrim)))/(2*a)
neg = (-b - (math.sqrt(discrim)))/(2*a)


if b > 0 and c > 0 and posi < 0:
  posi = -posi
  if neg < 0:
    neg = -neg

y = -b/2*a
vector = (neg+posi)/2, y)
```

With this code, I have my x intercept(s), and the vector, which is enough to create a parabola, I'm just not sure how to turn these values into a graph using MatPlotLib. Please ask any questions.

Comment: You need to plot simple parabola based on input parameters?

Comment: Essentially yes, but I'm having difficulty with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some corrections in You code. Below code will plot any parabola. You can add zero points and extreme point into you plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np

a = int(input('Input a: '))
b = int(input('Input b: '))
c = int(input('Input c: '))

# calculate delta and zero points
delta = b**2 - 4*a*c
if delta > 0:
    x_1 = (-b + math.sqrt(delta))/(2*a)
    x_2 = (-b - math.sqrt(delta))/(2*a)
if delta == 0:
    x_0 = -b/(2*a)
else:
    pass

# calculate parabola extreme coordinates
p = -b/(2*a)
q = -delta/(4*a)
extreme = [p,q]

# define parabola function
def parabola(x,a,b,c):
    y = a*x**2 + b*x + c
    return y

# plot function
x = np.linspace(int(p)-5,int(p)+5,100)
y = parabola(x,a,b,c)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.axhline(y=0, color='black', linestyle='-')
plt.axvline(x=0, color='black', linestyle='-')
plt.text(p-0.5, q-3, '[' + str(round(p,2)) +',' + str(round(q,2)) + ']',color='orange', fontsize=9)
plt.plot(p, q, marker="o")

if delta > 0:
    plt.plot(x_1, 0, marker="o", color='green')
    plt.text(x_1 - 0.5, 2, '[' + str(round(x_1,2)) + ']', color='green', fontsize=9)
    plt.plot(x_2, 0, marker="o", color='green')
    plt.text(x_2 - 0.5, 2, '[' + str(round(x_2,2)) + ']', color='green', fontsize=9)

if delta == 0:
    plt.plot(x_0, 0, marker="o", color='green')
    plt.text(x_0 - 0.5, 2, '[' + str(round(x_0,2)) + ']', color='green', fontsize=9)

plt.show()
```

**Sample result:**

[image]

Comment: An extra would be to test whether in case x_1, x_2 exist, that they are visible into the drawn range. Something like `if delta > 0: x = np.linspace(x_2 - 5, x_1 + 5, 100)`